# Finding a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^5-2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a closed form for the expression above. I know that Ramanujan gave a closed form for 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^3-2k}= \ln(2)-\frac{1}{2}
$$

I wonder if it is possible to find such a similarly simple and nice closed form for the above case. 
Wolfram guives answers involving Digamma or Polygamma functions, but I'm looking for a cleaner answer. It would be nice if someone could find such a thing...

Thanks.

Comment: The question is rather clear. He is interested in the sum in the title. The one in the body is an example of a sum that have a closed form.

Comment: @Umberto My apologies, I misread the question. Either way, interesting question.

Comment: And... which **mathematical** steps have you taken to solve this?

Comment: @zz20s Indeed it is... I simplified the term to be summed to $1/(2k \cdot ((2k)^2+1))$ but this seems also difficult to evalute (at least as the OP wants).

Comment: You do recall how to do partial fraction decomposition, yes?

Comment: So, the question becomes a special value of the digamma: evaluate $\mathrm{Re}\;\psi(i/2)$.  [The imaginary part is something in terms of $\coth(\pi/2)$.]

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ What happen if you change the $2$ by $3$? You can't play as you want to with series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may recall that,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k+a}=\psi(a+N+1)-\psi(a+1) \tag1
> $$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function $\psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$.

Then observe that
$$
\frac{4}{(2k)^5-2k}=\frac{1}{ 2 k-1}+\frac{1}{ 2 k+1}-\frac{2}{ k}+\frac{1}{ 2 k+i}+\frac{1}{ 2 k-i} \tag2
$$ summing from $k=1$ to $k=N$, gives 
$$
\begin{align}
&8\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{(2k)^5-2k}
\\\\&=2\psi(1/2+N)+\frac2{2N+1}-\psi(1/2)-\psi(3/2)-4\psi(1+N)+4\psi(1)
\\\\&+2\:\Re\:\psi(1+i/2+N)-2\:\Re\:\psi(1+i/2) \tag3
\end{align}$$ By letting $N \to \infty$, one gets a closed form formula in terms of special values of the [digamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15).

Comment: Quote: "Wolfram g(i)ves answers involving Digamma or Polygamma functions, but I'm looking for a cleaner answer".

Comment: Applying $(1)$ to $(2)$ makes $(3)$.

Comment: @Did, I doubt that the OP will find a digamma-free expression for his answer; the solution I get involves $\psi\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)$ and its conjugate, and as GEdgar notes in the comments, only its imaginary part has a known elementary form.

Comment: @J.M. I know, there is none. Does this imply that one should post answers rehashing digamma expressions already known to the OP?

Comment: @Did, since the OP did not show what he got that was so unsatisfactory (sadly, a usual matter), maybe a reminder is in order, or maybe the digamma expression OP got is not the simplest it could be.

Comment: @J.M. True, the question is, from a formal point of view, far from perfect. Proper reactions to this state of affairs are to post comments or to downvote the question, not to post offtopic answers (recall that the OP is after some "cleaner answer"). Personally, I would love to see somebody actually address the question and post a proof that no formula without digamma exists, that would be nice mathematics...

Comment: One question, how can you get a "closed form" if the digamma function does not converge on infinity?

Comment: @Masacroso Interestingly, the divergent parts (logarithmic terms) cancel.